# How to Lay Out Text Boxes with Even Spacing in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to draw an irregular grid of text boxes with even spacing between them in PowerPoint. Like this:[image: example of even spacing]

In HTML with CSS, I can create a grid or table and set the margin between the cells, like this: [image: set the "margin" between the cells]

But in Office, "margin" is equivalent to CSS's "padding", which only controls the space between the text and the border. Table Hierarchy and Architecture Layout SmartArt have uneven spacing between the boxes. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: `Insert -> Smart Art -> Hierarchy -> Table Hierarchy` looks like what you are looking for

Comment: Table Hierarchy has variable width between blocks: the smaller the blocks in that layer, the less space between them. I'm looking for even spacing between all blocks.